# SQL server 2008 R2 Database space issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

We have a database in production which is having little unused space and more unallocated space. We had a recent change in production that added a new table to this database and this has used all the unused space but still this has got lot of unallocated space left. Is this an issue if unused space is filled up? will there be any performance issue? could anyone please clarify on this?

Comment: Are you talking about spaces in the database files or on the server's hard drive? In any case: if database needs space it will try to grow (increase file size) the data file, provided autogrow setting is enabled, if the data file size cannot be increased, transaction will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is about the spaces in the dabase file. It is currently growing without any transaction failure. There is  lot of space on hard drive. Will there be any performance issue if database autogrows  or should we consider resizing the database..

Comment: Actually it is not even autogrowing. To be more clear, before the change, there was some unused space(2 GB) and Unallocated space(20GB) for the database. After the change, there is no more Ununsed space and Unallocated space is 18GB. Is this an issue to use Unallocated space?

Comment: I think this should answer your question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57253/autogrowth-shrink-and-database-performance